# How can I store logs that are replaced compared with original data in R?

Tags: r, gsub

I already asked and got [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70526361/mask-phone-number-in-r) about this topic.

However, additionally, I want to check which data are replaced in the new column. I just tried below,

`df$check <- str_match_all(df, "\\d{11}") %% unlist`

but, it cannot work. Ultimately, I want to get the below data set.

```
              original               edited       check
1        010-1234-5678        010-1234-5678            
2   John 010-8888-8888   John 010-8888-8888            
3 Phone: 010-1111-2222 Phone: 010-1111-2222            
4  Peter 018.1111.3333  Peter 018.1111.3333            
5 Year(2007,2019,2020) Year(2007,2019,2020)            
6    Alice 01077776666  Alice 010-9999-9999 01077776666
```

Here is my code.

```
x = c("010-1234-5678",
      "John 010-8888-8888",
      "Phone: 010-1111-2222",
      "Peter 018.1111.3333",
      "Year(2007,2019,2020)",
      "Alice 01077776666")

df = data.frame(
  original = x
)

df$edited <- gsub("\\d{11}", "010-9999-9999", df$original)

df$check <- c("","","","","","01077776666") # I want to know the way here.
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an `ifelse` using `` `==` `` you could test if the columns match, then if not, use `gsub` to match the first digit and get it and the rest of the string out of `"original"`.

```
transform(df, check=ifelse(!do.call(`==`, df[c("original", "edited")]), 
                           gsub('(\\D*)(\\d.*)', '\\2', original),
                           NA))
#               original               edited       check
# 1        010-1234-5678        010-1234-5678        <NA>
# 2   John 010-8888-8888   John 010-8888-8888        <NA>
# 3 Phone: 010-1111-2222 Phone: 010-1111-2222        <NA>
# 4  Peter 018.1111.3333  Peter 018.1111.3333        <NA>
# 5 Year(2007,2019,2020) Year(2007,2019,2020)        <NA>
# 6    Alice 01077776666  Alice 010-9999-9999 01077776666
```